# Declaration of ranges - object define error

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a aprt of my code where I declare ranges and give them names. I have two sheets in my workbook "ConsoSheet" and "Duplicated".

I have 5 ranges to declare, the first four work well. However the last one "Data_Temp" is causing me some trouble. I keep getting the error "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Can you see why ?

```
Dim DataOut As Range
   Dim crit As Range
   Dim LengthList As Range
   Dim Data As Range
   Dim Data_Temp As Range

   Set DataOut = Sheets("Duplicated").Range("=Duplicated!$I$1:$O$1")
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DataOut", RefersTo:=DataOut

   Set crit = Sheets("Duplicated").Range("=Duplicated!$R$1:$R$2")
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="crit", RefersTo:=crit

   Set LengthList = Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range("=ConsoSheet!$J$1")
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LengthList", RefersTo:=LengthList

   Set Data = Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range("=OFFSET(ConsoSheet!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(ConsoSheet!$A:$A),7)")
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Data", RefersTo:=Data

   Set Data_Temp = Sheets("Duplicated").Range("=OFFSET(Duplicated!$I$1;0;0;COUNTA(Duplicated!$I:$I);7)")
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Data_Temp", RefersTo:=Data_Temp
```

I tried changing the name of this particular range but the problem stays the same.

Comment: If my answer was correct then you should mark it by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do, it will award points and close the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 Set DataOut = Sheets("Duplicated").Range("=Duplicated!$I$1:$O$1")
```

Needs to be:

```
 Set DataOut = Sheets("Duplicated").Range("I1:O1")
```

You are mixing vba with worksheet formulas.

And this line:

```
Set Data = Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range("=OFFSET(ConsoSheet!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(ConsoSheet!$A:$A),7)")
```

to this:

```
Set Data = Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range(Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range("A1"),Sheets("ConsoSheet").Range("G1").End(xlDown))
```

You will need to change all the lines to fix the issue like above.